Gap between storm door and weatherproofing showing
We have a storm door that either has slowly fallen down a bit or was never installed correctly.  The door works fine, but we have this gap at the top which we think might be letting in mosquitoes and/or flies.  Is it possible to extend down the weatherstripping somehow, or how should I go about fixing this?


The limited view shows that the door is not hung correctly. Why, remains a mystery, but a good possibility is a loose top hinge.  The best solution is to correct the position of the door.

The easy way is to replace the weather stripping with a larger size.  This will not fix the problem of why the door is dropping/not square with the door frame.  As the first comment said, a loose top hinge is a common problem.  The fix can be simple as tightening the screws or replacing with longer screws.  Might even be easier than replacing stripping.

thank you to both of you, I'll check out the hinges. At first sight they look OK actually...

We gave the easy fixes.  Measuring the door frame from corner to corner(top to bottom) might show the frame out of square and harder work.
